# What should words be called that can be separated into two or more parts, each of which means the same as the word as a whole?

Tags: nouns, compounds

What should words be called that can be separated into two or more parts, each of which means the same as the word as a whole?

I know there are at least three words in English that fit this description. I remember *taxicab* (= taxi = cab) and *oleomargarine* (= oleo = margarine), but I keep forgetting the third one. *Jetplane* does not count because not all planes are jetplanes.

Comment: oleo and margarine are both just shortenings for a product which was originally called oleomargarine. If you count all shortenings, there might be a lot more examples. The same seems to be the case for taxicab.

Comment: Also: Cocktail.

Comment: It's a bit like an _appositional compound_ but where the two lexemes would have the same meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Barenaked
Bunnyrabbit
Forefront
Kittycat
Ratfink
Pussycat
Sodapop
Sumtotal
Taperecord
Tincan

Admittedly, some of those would more often be written with a hyphen (or even a space) to separate their component words.

Comment: The question was **not** asking for a list of such words, but "What should words be called that can be separated into two or more parts, each of which means the same as the word as a whole?" I'll make that clearer...

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Before Reg Dwight edited the question, the OP originally wrote: "I keep forgetting one, but I'll give the other two later (so you can have fun trying to figure them out)." Then he/she appended *oleomargarine* and *taxicab* as comments. I inferred from this that the OP was open to other suggestions, especially since the original version only asked what such words should be called *in the title*. So I answered that part of the question to which I was able to respond, before other people started changing the OP's own wording.

Comment: I warned you _The Foxhunter_ had been released. // Is there a term for answering edited questions before they've actually been edited?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I'd have to call that **preplying.**

Comment: I'll upvote 7 of your next 24 answers. (That's just a guesstimate.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Oh dear. That's a feeble grade of just 29/100. 100/29 would be a lot better.

Comment: Note that "taperecord" and "tincan" are not such words.  To tape-record (usually hypnenated) is to make an audio recording on tape -- there are many other ways to record something, and "tape" has many other meanings.  Similarly, "tin can" (rarely one word) means a "can" made out of tin (or, rather, tin-plated steel).  You can have a "can" made out of glass.

Comment: All niggles, quibbles and brabbles gratefully welcomed.

Comment: +1 Nice list, little niggly observations aside :) I'm just about to steal one  for a lesson. Thanks

Comment: For a disciple of W C Fields, voting **for** _anything_ is commendable. Though working _ratfink_ into an answer _is_ admittedly impressive. Bet you can't manage 7 quotes from Harpo.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Quite. That would just be bizarre.

Comment: :-) @HotLicks one of the definitions of *tape* is *record* http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tape?searchDictCode=all , and one of the definitions of *tin* is *air-tight can* http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tin?searchDictCode=all. Sorry Edwin, my bifocals failed me.

Comment: @GoodA.M. - But the definition of "tape" as "record" is simply an abbreviation of "tape-record".  Similarly "tin".

Answer (score 1):

According to the definition given by [The Gale Group](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tautology)

**tautology** may be used for even a single word AB where A = B:

> needless repetition of a concept in word or phrase; redundancy or
>   pleonasm. Also tautologism.

*Quagmire* is perhaps the traditional example.

Of course, this definition doesn't *require* that A = B **= AB**.